# Using SSL for MVC 4 applications

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ssl, paypal

My question is about SSL. In my scenario, I have an MVC 4 application where users can log in using the Simple Membership and place orders that are processed by an external application, in my case, PayPal. The question is, how important would a secured connection be in order to perform these tasks? In my mind, since there is an external application that processes the order, there should not be any need to have SSL, however, because the log in operation is taking place on the actual application, it would be an advantage to secure that connection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Paypal is a very secure platform for processing your payment so I wouldn't worry about it.

the only thing I see that you may or may not wanna worry about is the user/password which is transferred over the wire and without SSL they may get rubbed which is not too important for 2 reasons:

1: you are just starting a site and no one is willing to take time to crack it at this point. (you may consider SSL later on)

2: at this point, your website user and password will have no value to anyone. big websites like facebook, google, stackoverflow didnt have SSL for quite a while.

3: your users have to login to their paypal later on which is quite secure and even if not, is not your responsibility.

if you were accepting credit card info, I would have said 100% you need SSL, but Paypal is doing it for you.